# Yocto: add a statement in the default service file within a recipe

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I'd need to add a `Restart` statement within a default `.service` file, and was looking to an alternate solution to replacing the `.service` file with a custom one (which works).

The idea would be just adding the following "delta" requirement in a, e.g., `${systemd_system_unitdir}/my_service.d/override.conf` file:

```
[Service]
Restart=always
```

and then adding that file in a dedicated `.bbappend` recipe file.

Tests so far were not successful in adding the above statements in the deployed service file (despite the "delta" conf file being correctly deployed). Is this even a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that simply by `echo`ing that entry in a `do_install:append()` section in you `.bbappend` file. Something like:

```
do_install:append() {
    echo "[Service]\nRestart=always" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/wpa_supplicant/...
}
```

You can equally use `sed` to find and replace that section if there is already a file inplace.

`${sysconfdir}` will expanded to `/etc`. Check this file for more defined path variables: https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/conf/bitbake.conf?h=blinky

Comment: Brilliant idea, and it works. Thanks!